# В чем разница операций?

Tags: java

Учу java и решаю незамысловаты задачки на разных сайтах.
Так вот одна мне сломала голову, точнее даже две.

1. Какое значение будет иметь переменная number после выполнения этого кода?

```
int number = 5;
if(++number > 5 | ++number > 6) 
    number++;

// Ответ 8**
```

2. Какое значение будет иметь переменная number после выполнения этого кода?

```
int number = 5;
if(++number > 5 || ++number > 6) 
    number++; 

// Ответ 7**
```

Тут два оператора или || и |. В чем их разница?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: [operator `|`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html), [operator `||`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

Answer (score 2):

`|` - **побитовый** оператор *или*, в этом случае производится операция "побитовое или" между операндами, чтобы её посчитать, нужно выполнить и левый операнд и правый

`||` - **логический** оператор *или*, с логическими операторами среда исполнения использует оптимизации - если для вычисления истины или ложности достаточно выполнения левого операнда, то **правый операнд не вычисляется**, что и происходит в вашем случае (левый операнд истинен - значит и всё выражение истинно, независимо от значения правого операнда)

Answer (score 2):

Основное отличие в ленивости [оператора `||`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html). Если левый операнд равен `true` второй операнд **НЕ** вычисляется.

В то время как для [оператора `|`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) всегда вычисляются оба операнда.

В предоставленном коде это приводит к тому, что в первом случае `number` увеличивается три раза, два раза внутри условия `if`, и один раз в теле, а во втором - два раза, один раз внутри условия и один раз в теле.